# Linked Braces in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, braces

How can I, create a vertical line between the open brace and close brace in Visual Studio 2008 (C#), if you can't understand about what I'm talking, there's a following picture(Pic1).

[Pic1 - I want to do this with the braces]
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/vsbeforefonts.png

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say the most direct way of doing this would be to ask the person whose computer you took the screen shot on. Clearly, they have the configuration or add-in already set up.

Comment: Thanks was DeveExpress CodeRush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines are created by [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/), an addin with more that just brace matching.

Comment: Thanks was DeveExpress CodeRush.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) to me....

Specifically, the "Structural highlighting" feature:

[image]
<sub>(source: [devexpress.com](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/i/StructuralHighlightingInCSharp.gif))</sub>

Comment: Thanks was DeveExpress CodeRush.